# In VBA, how do I add a hyperlink to my comment object?

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink, comments

I am trying to create macros in Word to insert comments I frequently need to add to my documents.
I want to be able to add text, and below a hyperlink that leads to the source where this text was taken.

Here what the code looks like. I suspect the problem is with the ActiveDocument.Hyperlink.Add part, but I can't find a solution to make my macro target the active comment object rather than the ActiveDocument...

```
Sub new_comment()
'
' new_comment Macro
'
'
Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:= \_
"This is my text."
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= \_
"https://google.com" \_
, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="This is my source"

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

I tried manually adding the anchor text and the hyperlink while recording a macro and it didn't register my commands.

=== UPDATE ===

Tim's solution below works well, then I tried adding multiple code blocks, one for each preset comment I want to run in Word. Every subsequent comment I add using these macros will insert the hyperlink anchor in the first comment of the document.

So, if I run the three macros below in order, new_comment_1 and new_comment_2 would anchor their hyperlink somewhere in new_comment. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
Sub new_comment()

    Dim cmt As Comment

    Set cmt = Selection.Comments.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
                Text:="This is my text. This is my source.")
    
    HyperlinkComment cmt, "This is my source", "https://google.com"
    
End Sub

Sub HyperlinkComment(cmt As Comment, linkText As String, URL As String)
    Dim p As Long, rng As Range
    Set rng = cmt.Range
    p = InStr(1, cmt.Range.Text, linkText, vbTextCompare)
    If p > 0 Then
        rng.SetRange Start:=p, End:=p + Len(linkText)
        cmt.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=URL
    End If
End Sub

Sub new_comment_1()

    Dim cmt As Comment

    Set cmt = Selection.Comments.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
                Text:="This is my second preset comment. This is my second source.")
    
    HyperlinkComment cmt, "This is my second source.", "https://www.wikipedia.org/"
    
End Sub

Sub new_comment_2()

    Dim cmt As Comment

    Set cmt = Selection.Comments.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
                Text:="This is my third preset comment. This is my third source.")
    
    HyperlinkComment cmt, "This is my third source.", "https://www.un.org/en/"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: updated - removed the `SetRange` call in `HyperlinkComment` and used `MoveStart` / `MoveEnd` instead, which seems to have fixed things.

Something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
 
    Dim doc As Document, i As Long
    
    
    Set doc = ThisDocument
    
    'for testing - remove any existing comments
    For i = doc.Comments.Count To 1 Step -1
        doc.Comments(i).Delete
    Next i
    
    new_comment doc.Paragraphs(1).Range, "This is my text. This is my source....", _
                "This is my source", "https://google.com"
                
    
    new_comment doc.Paragraphs(3).Range, "This is my text2. This is my source2....", _
                "This is my source", "https://yahoo.com"
                            
    
    new_comment doc.Paragraphs(5).Range, "This is my text3. This is my source3....", _
                "This is my source", "https://www.wikipedia.org"


End Sub


Sub new_comment(rng As Range, txt As String, linktxt As String, URL As String)

    Dim cmt As Comment

    Set cmt = rng.Parent.Comments.add(Range:=rng, Text:=txt)
    HyperlinkComment cmt, linktxt, URL
    
End Sub

Sub HyperlinkComment(cmt As Comment, linkText As String, URL As String)
    Dim p As Long, rng As Range, cmtLen As Long, p2 As Long
    Set rng = cmt.Range
    cmtLen = Len(rng.Text)
    p = InStr(1, cmt.Range.Text, linkText, vbTextCompare)
    p2 = p + Len(linkText)
    If p > 0 Then
        rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, p - 1
        If p2 < cmtLen Then rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -(cmtLen - p2) - 1
        cmt.Parent.Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=rng, Address:=URL
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim.
However, I just ran your code in VBA, it does create a comment with "This is my text. This is my source.", but "This is my source." has no hyperlink on it.

Comment: Working for me as posted.  Have you debugged?  For example does the `If p > 0 Then` test pass?

Comment: Hi Tim, I tinkered with your code a little bit and I'm having issues with anchors. I have updated the original post.

Comment: I have been using this code all week, works as intended for inserting preset comments.. 
However, when I create a new Word document, this code always creates a "This is my text. This is my source...." comment at the top of the blank document.

Comment: There's nothing in this code which auto-runs, so I'm not sure why it would create that comment?   Did you make some changes?

Comment: I didn't do any change. I thought it could have been the "Tester" subroutine, since this is where I find the text "This is my text. This is my source...." but the comment is still there when I create a new document even after removing that sub.
Interestingly, the comment is always dated June 5, 2023 at 08:26 am.

Comment: Seems like there may be a comment in your document template (Normal.dotm) ?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea

Comment: I'll look into this, it's likely a problem with normal.dotm
Thanks!